# I have 2 while loops but i want to call only one. Is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that show some data from 2 different tables in database. My script is working but i have call 2 while loops for each table. My question is, Can i use only one loop for both tables? Thanks All!!!!!

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
        $kontata_gas = "select id, supervizori, crt_gas, operatori, data, status, nome, cognome, tel, pdr, codice_fiscale from kontrata_gas where (data between '$data_e_inserimit' and '$data_e_inserimit_2' or tel='$tel' or codice_fiscale='$fiscale' or pdr='$POD_PDR')";
        $result_kontata_gas = mysqli_query($dbCon, $kontata_gas);
        if(!$result_kontata_gas) {
            die("Error1");
        }

        $kontata_luce = "select id, supervizori, crt_luce, operatori, data, status, nome, cognome, tel, pod, codice_fiscale from kontrata_luce where (data between '$data_e_inserimit' and '$data_e_inserimit_2' or tel='$tel' or codice_fiscale='$fiscale' or pod='$POD_PDR')";
        $result_kontata_luce = mysqli_query($dbCon, $kontata_luce);
        if(!$result_kontata_luce) {
            die("Error2");
        }   

    echo "<table style='width:auto;'>
        <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>TIPO CONTRATTO</td>
        <td>OPERATOR</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>NOME</td>
        <td>COGNOME</td>
        <td>TEL</td>
        <td>PDR / POD</td>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_kontata_gas)) { //first loop
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<tr>
            <td>"."<a href='main.php?backoffice=&mod_contratto=gas_$id'><img id='img' src='images/modify.png'></a>".$row['id']."</td>
            <td>".$row['crt_gas']."</td>
            <td>".$row['operatori']."</td>
            <td>".$row['data']."</td>
            <td>".$row['status']."</td>
            <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
            <td>".$row['cognome']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tel']."</td>
            <td>".$row['pdr']."</td>
            </tr>";
            $id++;
    }
        "<tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>TIPO CONTRATTO</td>
        <td>OPERATOR</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>NOME</td>
        <td>COGNOME</td>
        <td>TEL</td>
        <td>PDR / POD</td>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_kontata_luce)) { // second loop
        $id = $row['id'];
        $luce = $row['crt_luce'];
        echo "<tr>
            <td>"."<a href='main.php?backoffice=&mod_contratto=luce_$id'><img id='img' src='images/modify.png'></a>".$row['id']."</td>
            <td>".$row['crt_luce']."</td>
            <td>".$row['operatori']."</td>
            <td>".$row['data']."</td>
            <td>".$row['status']."</td>
            <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
            <td>".$row['cognome']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tel']."</td>
            <td>".$row['pod']."</td>
            </tr>";
            $id++;
    }

        echo "</table>";
        $_SESSION['$id'] = @$id;
        $_SESSION['$gas'] = @$gas;
        $_SESSION['$luce'] = @$luce;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you show your kontata_gas query ?

Comment: this is it. $kontata_gas = "select id, supervizori, crt_gas, operatori, data, status, nome, cognome, tel, pdr, codice_fiscale from kontrata_gas where (data between '$data_e_inserimit' and '$data_e_inserimit_2' or tel='$tel' or codice_fiscale='$fiscale' or pdr='$POD_PDR')";
  $result_kontata_gas = mysqli_query($dbCon, $kontata_gas);
  if(!$result_kontata_gas) {
   die("Error1");
  }

Comment: Edit your question and paste in the code there, reading code in the comments is virtually impossible.

Comment: call one while will not improve your code. maybe you sould use function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure since you show only one sql query, but you could probably use union (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to combine both sql querys.

Comment: Both querys have only 2 different rows everything else is the same, $kontata_gas has : crt_gas and pdr.                                          $kontata_luce has: crt_luce and pod.

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays have the same fields, you can make a function passing it the array and returning (or printing) the table.

```
printTable($result_kontata_gas);
printTable($result_kontata_luce);

function printTable($array) {
    echo "<table style='width:auto;'>
        <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>TIPO CONTRATTO</td>
        <td>OPERATOR</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>NOME</td>
        <td>COGNOME</td>
        <td>TEL</td>
        <td>PDR / POD</td>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($array)) { //first loop
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<tr>
            <td>"."<a href='main.php?backoffice=&mod_contratto=gas_$id'><img id='img' src='images/modify.png'></a>".$row['id']."</td>
            <td>".$row['crt_gas']."</td>
            <td>".$row['operatori']."</td>
            <td>".$row['data']."</td>
            <td>".$row['status']."</td>
            <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
            <td>".$row['cognome']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tel']."</td>
            <td>".$row['pdr']."</td>
            </tr>";
            $id++;
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Or you can make a function and return the arrays already fetched and make 2 different variables one for each table and concatenate in them their own array info.